# Reading a closed window in PySimpleGui password app

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm creating a small software database program with buttons on PySimpleGui, and one of the buttons that I have in my code is "delete" button. I want to put a password on that button in order to be used from only supervisors. When I created the .py file and imported it in my main file for the database program, I'm pressing the button "delete" and when I want to close the window, before I put a passcode it says " You have tried 100 times to read a closed window. You need to add a check for event == WIN_CLOSED" The problem is in line 22 `event, values = password_window.read()`

Here is the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import hashlib

def protect():
        layout = [
                [sg.Text('Въведете парола:', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText('', key='-PASSWORD-', password_char='*', size=(20, 1))],
                [sg.Button("Потвърди"),sg.Button("Отмени")]
                ]

        password_window = sg.Window('Функция изискваща достъп на управител', layout, modal=True)

        def verify_password(password):
                hash = '112e3f234c4d002cewc328e0be632rf34fer7181csf940b25c79d7bttrh3598ce12'
                password_utf = password.encode('utf-8')
                password_hash = hashlib.sha256(password_utf).hexdigest()
                print(password_hash)
                if hash == password_hash:
                        return True
                return False
        
        while True:
                event, values = password_window.read()
                if event == "Отмени" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                        password_window.close()
                        
                if event == 'Потвърди':
                        password_input_value = values['-PASSWORD-']
                        if verify_password(password_input_value):
                                break
                        else:
                                continue
```

I tried to pass it, also to continue on it, but when I put for example:

```
while True:
    event, values = password_window.read()
    if event == "Отмени" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            password_window.close()
                 else:
                    continue
```

It's forwarding me and skipping the window with the password that I have to put. Any ideas how to fix it, so when I close the password window, to return to the main window database?

Comment: Where's the button `delete` ? Maybe you can try to add statemenet `break` after `password_window.close()` to break from the event loop.

Comment: The delete button is in the other python file. It looks like that:


elif event == 'Delete':
        TEST_PASSWORD.protect()
        if values['-TABLE-']==[]:
            sg.popup('Моля изберете ред с информация')
        else:
            if sg.popup_ok_cancel('Потвърди изтриване?') == 'OK':
                del td[values['-TABLE-'][0]]
                window['-TABLE-'].update(values=td)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the "You have tried 100 times" message is because you are closing the window, but still remain in the while loop, which repeatedly tries to read data from the closed window. As Jason Yang suggests, you need to break out of the while loop. Also the best place to close the window is outside the while loop - that way you can be certain that you will never be inside the while loop with a closed window.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import hashlib

def protect():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Въведете парола:', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText('', key='-PASSWORD-', password_char='*', size=(20, 1))],
        [sg.Button("Confirm"),sg.Button("Delete")]
    ]

    password_window = sg.Window('Функция изискваща достъп на управител', layout, modal=True)

    def verify_password(password):
        hash = '112e3f234c4d002cewc328e0be632rf34fer7181csf940b25c79d7bttrh3598ce12'
        password_utf = password.encode('utf-8')
        password_hash = hashlib.sha256(password_utf).hexdigest()
        print(password_hash)
        if hash == password_hash:
            return True
        return False

    while True:
        event, values = password_window.read()
        if event == "Delete" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        if event == 'Confirm':
            password_input_value = values['-PASSWORD-']
            if verify_password(password_input_value):
                break
            else:
                continue

    password_window.close()

protect()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is also working, but i already fixed the issue with a popup window. Thank you your suggestion is very useful for future projects! :)

Comment: Sure, just cannot find how to ^^

Comment: Just click the checkmark icon (✓) on the left hand side associated with the answer. It should turn green.